# How to include variable in string that begins with $ for escaping

Tags: bash

I found for bash, using `$'string'` allows for escape characters. I also want to use a variable in the string like `$'string ${var}'`. However, the variable is not expanded and the output is `string ${var}`. Is there a way to use a variable in this type of string?

The reason I am using the string method with the dollar sign in front is to use the hexcode for a custom font to get a symbol. The desired goal is shown below.

```
sybmol='\uF107'
echo $'\uF101 ${symbol}'
```

Comment: Also, is there a name for using a string of this format, with a dollar sign in front? All other answers I found related to this just refer to it is `$'string'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpretation of `\u` happens when the string is defined. You should use that quoting with the definition of `symbol` itself:

```
symbol=$'\uF107'
```

Then you can simply use two different kinds of quoting when specifying the argument of `echo`.

```
echo $'\uF101'"${symbol}"
```

The two quoted strings are implicitly concatenated into a single word by the shell.

Note that `$'...'` expands the escape sequence *immediately*, while `echo` itself can (via the `-e` option) expand similar sequences.

```
symbol='\uF107'
echo -e '\uF101'"$symobl"
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
symbol='\uF107'
echo -e "\uF101 ${symbol}"
```

or

```
printf '%b\n'  "\uF101 ${symbol}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize my issue was with how powerlevel10k interprets the string. I should have checked and seen that a regular string works fine with echo, which is how I asked the question. I just didn't want to over complicate it by including too much powerlevel10k environment. For some reason, powerlevel10k doesn't convert the hexcodes to the font unless it has the `$'string'` format from what I can tell.